# Android speech to text works in emulator but not on phone

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I'm trying to write a speech to text app for android. Now the app doesn't crash on the emulator, but when I upload it to a samsung galaxy s 1900 I get following error messages in eclipse:

```
11-05 17:43:48.814: I/dalvikvm(3092): Could not find method com.example.speechtotext.MainActivity.getActionBar, referenced from method com.example.speechtotext.MainActivity.onCreate
11-05 17:43:48.818: W/dalvikvm(3092): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3036: Lcom/example/speechtotext/MainActivity;.getActionBar ()Landroid/app/ActionBar;
11-05 17:43:48.818: D/dalvikvm(3092): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0009
11-05 17:43:48.818: D/dalvikvm(3092): VFY: dead code 0x000c-0061 in Lcom/example/speechtotext/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
11-05 17:43:48.896: D/AndroidRuntime(3092): Shutting down VM
11-05 17:43:48.900: W/dalvikvm(3092): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.speechtotext.MainActivity.getActionBar
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at com.example.speechtotext.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
11-05 17:43:48.900: E/AndroidRuntime(3092):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 17:44:11.343: I/dalvikvm(3092): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-05 17:44:12.724: E/dalvikvm(3092): Failed to write stack traces to /data/anr/traces.txt (805 of 2366): Unknown error: 0
11-05 17:44:22.165: I/Process(3092): Sending signal. PID: 3092 SIG: 9
```

firmware version 2.2 on the phone.

When running in emulator the program just sais that speech isn't supported in the emulator, no crash though.

This my code:

```
package com.example.speechtotext;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnInitListener {

    private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    private TextToSpeech myTTS;
    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    private ListView mList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speak);
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

        // Get display items for later interaction
        Button speakButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
        if (activities.size() != 0) {
            speakButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {
            speakButton2.setEnabled(false);
            speakButton2.setText("Recognizer not present");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Indien men op de speakbutton klikt
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        EditText enteredText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter);
        String words = enteredText.getText().toString();
        speakWords(words);

        if (arg0.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
        }
    }

    // Zorgt voor de spraak
    private void speakWords(String speech) {
        // myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null); zorgt dat de app
        // het toevoegt aan de queue zodat het wacht tot de vorige speech
        // opdracht uitgesproken is
        myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    // Controleren of de data beschikbaar is
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            } else {
                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent
                        .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it
            // could have heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                "Speech recognition demo");
        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    // Taal juist zetten en indien er een fout is geeft men een foutboodschap
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

I've checked that the min API isn't to high, but eclipse has set that to 2.2 so I think thats fine.

Someone an idea what could be wrong or how to debug?

Kind regards,

Comment: getActionBar requires API level 11 (honeycomb)

Comment: Show us your xml configurations.

Comment: Mukul Goel, why do you have the energy to write that? I don't get it :p don't you get frustrated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use [`ActionBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) on device running Android 2.2 (API level 8), but `ActionBar` was added in API level 11.

So you have basically two options here:

1. Don't use `ActionBar` in your app.
2. Use [`ActionBarSherlock`](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library, it backports action bar back to Android 2.x (though you still need to make some minor changes in your code, read the docs of `ActionBarSherlock` for more details).

Comment: Thanks, or I could just update to the newest version on my phone right?

Comment: If you could update your phone's OS to API level 11 or higher, the app would work on your phone. However, you still have a problem if you install it on a device running Android 2.x - it will crash. To make it stable you should set `android:minSdkVersion="11"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to prevent the app from being installed on older devices. Still, I suggest the preferred solution is to utilize `ActionBarSherlock`.