# Text to speech works on emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech

I have gone through almost all the links related to this topic but haven't found any suitable answer. I am trying to build a basic text to speech application. It works perfectly fine on the emulator. But when i run it on my phone, it shows language not supported. 
I guess this has something to do with the locale. The default locale set in my phone is `en_US`
My code is as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Method yet to be defined
            speakOut();
        }

    });
}

public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // TTS is successfully initialized
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        // Setting speech language
        // System.out.println(Locale.getAvailableLocales());
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
        // int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
        // If your device doesn't support language you set above
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            // Cook simple toast message with message
            Toast.makeText(this, "Language not supported",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");

        } else {
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
        }
        // TTS is not initialized properly
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "TTS Initilization Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }
}

private void speakOut() {
    // Get the text typed
    String text = txtText.getText().toString();
    // If no text is typed, tts will read out 'You haven't typed text'
    // else it reads out the text you typed
    if (text.length() == 0) {
        tts.speak("You haven't typed text", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    } else {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

}

public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

even if i use `int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());` instead of `Locale.ENGLISH`, it shows the same language not supported message

LOGCAT ERROR:

```
02-26 16:24:57.492: I/TextToSpeech.java(23356): initTts() successfully bound to service
02-26 16:24:58.015: E/TTS(23356): Language is not supported
```

I am running this on my phone- Samsung Galaxy-Y (GT-S5360) with Android version 2.3.6

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236771/android-speech-to-text-works-in-emulator-but-not-on-phone

Comment: Did you get any error? Show error log please if possible

Comment: Please add your initialization code of tts object and it would help if you specify your phone and its os version

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara: the link u have specified is related to 'SPEECH-TO-TEXT' and i am implementing 'TEXT-TO-SPEECH'. also, the error occured is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution myself. the problem was that the locales available on the android default tts engine did not match those on my phone.
i installed another tts engine and it works perfectly fine with it.

Comment: What "other" tts did you installed?